# Neo4j recovering a database with a massive transaction log (in the legacy index dir)

Tags: transactions, neo4j

The neo4j [documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-java-embedded-hello-world.html) has this to say about transactions :

```
// Now, transaction handling in Neo4j is very easy
try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )
{
    // Database operations go here
    tx.success();
}
```

I knew this smelled fishy, and only looked into it AFTER I had the problem. It should actually be :

```
// Transaction handling in neo4j is slightly less easier , omg a tx.close() :D 
try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )
{
    // Database operations go here
    tx.success();
}
finally {
  tx.close()
}
```

I ran a massive batch full text indexing operation, and now I can't seem to start the db up. (GC errors with shell, other exception when doing it from my embedded app with 6g Heap).

How do I destroy the transaction log (and Yes I WILL run the db in batch inserter mode after this) ?

p.s.,

```
➜  index  pwd
/Users/hassan/code/scala/avro/chunks.db/index
➜  index  ls
lucene            lucene.log.2      lucene.log.v0     lucene.log.v10    lucene.log.v12    lucene.log.v14    lucene.log.v3     lucene.log.v5     lucene.log.v7     lucene.log.v9
lucene-store.db   lucene.log.active lucene.log.v1     lucene.log.v11    lucene.log.v13    lucene.log.v2     lucene.log.v4     lucene.log.v6     lucene.log.v8
```

Will obliterating `*.log` do the trick or are these logs registered somewhere important --i.e, deleting them causes further issues?

**Recommendation:**

The shell should have some logic to deal with situations like this. It should have asked me to make some choices.

1. increase the Heap size at least (even though it would not have helped).
2. Offer to delete certain transaction logs etc (at least if a tool does it, a user can be assured it will be done cleanly).

Better yet the transaction replay logic should know how to work outside the confines of the JVM heap (like any transactional db can).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the log files in the index directory seems to do the trick. No exceptions are thrown during startup so I assume the db is healthy. A neo4j dev can flesh this out if they will.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the first `try()` version is the same as the second.

Neo4j's transactions implement `AutoClosable` so the java try-with-resource handling will call `tx.close()` correctly at the end of the try block.

For not keeping logical logs you can add a config option like:

```
keep_logical_logs=false

or

keep_logical_logs=2 days

or

keep_logical_logs=500M
```

Comment: hmm, could this be because I am using Scala ? I say this because my db shutdown correctly and I was left with a 1GB log. Then when I put the the `finally tx.close` in it worked ok.